# Appending 'variables' to a Construction Environment

Tags: scons

I need to add platform-specific build variables to a SCons script I'm writing, and to do this, as far as I know, I need to create a Construction Environment before defining the variables so that I can actually check the platform (`env['PLATFORM']` etc.) If I do this, I have to append the variables afterwards, but for some reason it's not working.

```
env = Environment()
vars = Variables()
if env['PLATFORM'] == 'win32':
    default_prefix = 'C:\Program Files\Example'
elif env['PLATFORM'] == 'posix':
    default_prefix = '/usr/local/example'
vars.Add(PathVariable('prefix', 'installation path', default_prefix))
env.Append(variables = vars)

print env['prefix'] # error
```

I've found that a workaround is to just create the Environment again

```
env = Environment(variables = var)
```

but I was wondering if there's a better way, and why appending it doesn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing what you are looking for here but is it this:

```
Update(env,variables)
```

Using this function you update the environment with the variables argument.

I think the reason for the Append(variables=x) doesn't work is that the variables isn't 
a part of the "dictionary" environment, actually, if you pass variables into the constructor of the environment, inside the constructor the variables object will update the environment.

Comment: `vars.Update(env)` works for me. Is the second parameter for extra build variables? Thanks again!

Comment: The second variable is for the free function.

Answer (score 0):

I usually fetch the platform from

```
platform = Environment()["PLATFORM"]
```

then I can create the environment based on this knowledge.

Comment: Thanks. That's slightly better I suppose, but I wonder if there's a way without creating the Environment again, and I still don't understand why appending doesn't work.